# How to write unit test when you use Future?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, future

I've wrote a class with some functions that does HTTP calls and returns a `Future[String]`. I use those functions inside a method that I need to write some tests:

```
def score(rawEvent: Json) = {
  httpService
    .get("name", formatJsonAttribute(rawEvent.name))
    .onComplete { op =>
      op.map { json =>
        //What must be tested
      }
    }
}
```

The function `onComplete` doesn't have a return type - it returns `Unit`. How can I replace that `onComplete` to make my function return something to be tested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely agree with @Michal, that you should always prefer `map` to `onComplete` with `Future`s.  However I'd like to point out that, as you said yourself, what you wish to test is not the HTTP call itself (which relies on an HTTP client you probably don't need to test, a response from a server on which you may have no control, ...), but what you do with its answer.

So why not write a test, not on the function `score`, but on the function you wrote in your `onComplete` (or `map`, if you decided to change it)?

That way you will be able to test it with precise values for `json`, that you may wish to define as the result you will get from the server, but that you can control completely (for instance, you could test border cases without forcing your server to give unusual responses).

Testing that the two (HTTP call and callback function) sit well together is not a unit-test question, but an integration-test question, and should be done only once you know that your function does what is expected of it.

At that time, you will effectively need to check the value of a `Future`, in which case, you can use `Await.result` as @Michal suggested, or use the relevant constructs that your test framework gives. For instance, scalatest has an `AsyncTestSuite` trait for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` instead of `onComplete`. It will also provide you with resolved value inside mapping function. The return type of `score` function will be `Future[T]` where `T` will be the result type of your processing. 
In the tests you can use `scala.concurrent.Await.result()` function.

Comment: So i should just to remove that line `.onComplete { op =>` and use `map`?

Comment: Yes, as it would transform one future into another. Function given as argument to `map` over `Future` is executed when `Future` is successfully completed.

Comment: Yes. I think about `Future[T]` as being like a box that **will** hold a value in the future. When you map a function over it, the function will be applied when that value appears.

I would advise unit testing that function itself, without any Futures involved. If you start having `Await` in your tests then they may start to take a looong time...